# Splitting time stamps into two columns

Tags: r, date

I have a column with ID and for each ID several even dates. I want to create two columns with rows for each id one column with the first date and the other with the next consecutive date. The next row for the ID should have the entry in the previous row second column and the next consecutive date for this ID. An example:

This is the data I have

```
     id       date 
1       1 2015-01-01       
2       1 2015-01-18       
3       1 2015-08-02    
4       2 2015-01-01   
5       2 2015-01-13     
6       3 2015-01-01
```

This is data I want

```
   id       date1       date2
1       1 2015-01-01    2015-01-18   
2       1 2015-01-18    2015-08-02   
3       1 2015-08-02    NA
4       2 2015-01-01    2015-01-13
5       2 2015-01-13    NA 
6       3 2015-01-01    NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(date2 = lead(date))

     id       date      date2
  (int)     (fctr)     (fctr)
1     1 2015-01-01 2015-01-18
2     1 2015-01-18 2015-08-02
3     1 2015-08-02         NA
4     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-13
5     2 2015-01-13         NA
6     3 2015-01-01         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, you can do as follow:

```
require(data.table)
DT[, .(date1 = date, date2 = shift(date, type = "lead")), by = id]
```

Or simply (also mentioned by @docendodiscimus)

```
DT[, date2 := shift(date, type = "lead"), by = id]
```

Also, if you are interested on making a recursive `n` columns (edited, taking advantage of @docendodiscimus comment to simplify the code)

```
i = 1:5
DT[, paste0("date", i+1) := shift(date, i, type = "lead"), by = id]
```

Comment: I'd rather suggest `DT[, date2 := shift(date, 1L, type="lead"), by = id]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus sure! I just try to comply to OP's desired result

Comment: For your "recursive" implementation, this could be done as `n <- 1:5; dt[, paste0("date", n) := shift(date, n, type = "lead"), by = id]` too, since `shift`'s n parameter is vectorized

Comment: @docendodiscimus cool. I didn't know `shift` could be used that way

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution using [`transform()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html) and [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html):

```
transform(df,date1=date,date2=ave(date,id,FUN=function(x) c(x[-1L],NA)),date=NULL);
##   id      date1      date2
## 1  1 2015-01-01 2015-01-18
## 2  1 2015-01-18 2015-08-02
## 3  1 2015-08-02       <NA>
## 4  2 2015-01-01 2015-01-13
## 5  2 2015-01-13       <NA>
## 6  3 2015-01-01       <NA>
```

The above line of code produces a copy of the data.frame. The return value can be assigned over the original `df`, assigned to a new variable, or passed as an argument/operand to a function/operator. If you want to modify it in-place, which would be a more efficient way to overwrite `df`, you can do this:

```
df$date2 <- ave(df$date,df$id,FUN=function(x) c(x[-1L],NA));
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=='date'] <- 'date1';
df;
##   id      date1      date2
## 1  1 2015-01-01 2015-01-18
## 2  1 2015-01-18 2015-08-02
## 3  1 2015-08-02       <NA>
## 4  2 2015-01-01 2015-01-13
## 5  2 2015-01-13       <NA>
## 6  3 2015-01-01       <NA>
```

Comment: I think its unfair to newbies to post an answer using `transform` without warning them that the R functional paradigm means that your code will have no lasting effect on the value of `df`.

Comment: @42- I take your point, edited my answer accordingly. Although your language is a little bit harsh. I wasn't trying to mislead.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$date2 = ifelse(df$id==c(df$id[-1],-1), c(df$date[-1],NA), NA)
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately `ifelse()` is finicky, and doesn't respect the classes of the `yes` and `no` arguments. So this solution won't work if `date` is a `Date` type (or a `factor` type). If `Date`, you'll either have to coerce back to `Date` afterward, or use a different approach from `ifelse()`. It does work if `date` is `character`, however.